# Examples of test frameworks on python

Tags: python, testing

I have a bit wide question. Maybe someone knows where I can find good examples of functional test frameworks on python. 
I'm working on functional tests on python 2.5. I use standart unittest framework, but maybe where is some better ways, with support of nice html reporting. 
Also maybe where is examples of tests structure.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuantly I dont have that much experience with testing in Python, but I found these links which seems to contain a lot of useful information:

The sites below lists a lot of different test frameworks. One of which is called TestOOB and has html/xml reporting.

- https://pythonhosted.org/testing/
- http://pycheesecake.org/wiki/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy

O'reilly also has a free book on test driven python development which can be found here:

- http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/index.html

This site also has some information and examples of different testing frameworks.

- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/